# Consulta de muchos a uno laravel

Tags: php, eloquent

Tengo una duda en un controlador con una relacion de muchos(Producto) a uno(Marca), Intento buscar en Producto para luego mostrar la relación 'Marca' pero por lo visto tengo un error porque al usar `where()` para buscar en Producto  y luego mostrar la relacion el controlador me lo hace al revés me usa el `where()` en la tabla relacionada dándome el error de que el campo 'enlace_id'no existe en la tabla 'marca' pero lo que yo quiero es buscar enlace_id en la tabla producto.

```
$ejemplo = Producto::where('enlace_id', $id)->with('marca')->get();
```

**Modelo Producto**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'enlace_id'
    ];

    public function marca()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Marca', 'id', 'enlace_id');
      }

}
```

**Modelo Marca**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Marca extends Model
{

  protected $fillable = ['nombre'];


   public function producto()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\producto', 'enlace_id', 'id');
  }

}
```

Comment: Podrias poner como tienes tus modelos, y la estructura de tus tablas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu consulta que haces en una línea, podrías hacerlo de dos pasos de esta manera:
Ejemplo:

```
$marcas = Marca::select('id')->get();
return Producto::whereIn('enlace_id', $marcas->toArray())->get();
```

Así, buscarías en la tabla producto como quieres.

Un saludo.

Comment: Me funciona perfecto no te imaginas lo agradecido que te estoy llevo varios días sin dar con la solución GRACIAS.

Comment: Muy buena la lógica, me sirvió a mí también, si saben como hacerlo desde el modelo agradecería también los aportes :)